# If i add logos of betting apps in my video is this will be haram or halal

Tags: halal-haram

I have a instragram page so if i add logo of betting website/app and earn money from them then it will be haram or halal

Answer (score 0):

Based on this verse, helping sinners is prohibited.

> قَالَ رَبِّ بِمَآ أَنۡعَمۡتَ عَلَيَّ فَلَنۡ أَكُونَ ظَهِيرٗا
> لِّلۡمُجۡرِمِينَ  He said:
>
> "My Lord, with what you blessed on me, so I
> will never/not be a supporter/helper to the
> criminals/sinners."[(17)](https://quran.inoor.ir/en/ayah/28/17/)